# Empty json in my pages

Tags: php, json

I am use JSON in my php pages. I am put in json data from my mysql datebase. But json is empty or I'm not doing it correctly. What I do not correctly?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Файл firstsql.php
$host='my.db-host.com'; // имя хоста (уточняется у провайдера)
$database='db'; // имя базы данных, которую вы должны создать
$user='username'; // заданное вами имя пользователя, либо определенное провайдером
$pswd='password'; // заданный вами пароль

$dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Не могу подключиться к базе.");
$query = "SELECT * FROM `kordinates`";
$res = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
$json_data =     array('imei'=>".$row['imei'].",'dolgota'=>".$row['dolgota'].",'shirota'=>".$row['shirota'].",'date'=>".$row['date'].");
echo json_encode($json_data);
}
```

If I try do

```
echo "".$row['imei']."<br>\n";
```

It is work. And I have my data. But  `$json_data = array('imei'=>"...`  not work. Why?

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this ,first of all you need to push all values in a array as you are looping through the data set getting from Database, secondly you need to remove double inverted commas around the values in a array you are using inside while loop

```
           $json_data = array()
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
            $json_data[] =  array('imei'=>$row['imei'],'dolgota'=>$row['dolgota'],'shirota'=>$row['shirota'],'date'=>$row['date']);

            }
          echo json_encode($json_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should remove the credentials required to the connection of the source you published.
Now I think that you should remove the `"` and `.` around the vars $rows when you build your array.
Finally functions MySql are deprecated, you should instead use the [mysqli() ones](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
     $json_data=array('imei'=>$row['imei'],'dolgota'=>$row['dolgota'],'shirota'=>$row['shirota'],'date'=>$ro['date']);
}
echo json_encode($json_data);
```

Remove double quotes and put json_encode($json_data) outside while